# Ubuntu 18.04 airplane mode blocked

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a problem with my network ,my computer is stuck in airplane mode and I can't disable it .The os is Ubuntu 18.04.I have already used rfkill unblock all , restarted the computer even used fn+wifi(Button) but all those things do not change something to the situation.

Comment: Do you mean to say the computer is stuck in Airplane mode and you cannot disable this mode, or that you cannot ENABLE airplane mode? Please use the edit button to make your question more clear

Comment: Have you tried to turn airplanbe mode on/off with terminal? `nmcli r wifi on` (or `off`) See https://askubuntu.com/questions/348262/turn-airplane-mode-on-off-via-terminal'

Comment: Yes I have done it but Always nothing